# Service for managing outbound webhooks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, webhooks

I'm trying to find a service that will manage my outbound webhooks for me. Something that I can push a message to with the URL that needs to be called, method, payload, etc and have it handle retries, log failures, etc.

I feel like this process is relatively trivial, so I'd rather not re-create the wheel on our own platform.

We're running on Google Cloud, so I'd prefer something on GCE if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

There is no top level Google Cloud service with direct support just for making outbound HTTP requests.

## [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/)

The closest that you can use is [`Cloud Functions`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/), a serverless way to trigger and consume events. Using Cloud functions you can [write a handler in a Node.js module](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/), which can look at the incoming payload in the trigger and perform the desired action.

Cloud Functions [supports the following native triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/):

> - [HTTP Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http)
> - [Cloud Pub/Sub Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub)
> - [Cloud Storage Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage)
> - [Direct Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/direct)

Many Google Cloud services provide integration with Cloud Pub/Sub, and hence can be used to trigger the cloud function from variety of places.

As per the [Cloud Function Quota documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas), your function can execute up to [540 seconds](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#time_limits), which gives you ample time to handle retries for your requests if needed.

> **Quota** - Max function duration
>
> **Description** - The maximum amount of time
> a function can run before it's forcibly terminated
>
> **Limit** - 540 seconds
>
> **Can be increased** - No

## [App Engine Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/)

If what you are looking for is serverless with some form of async task scheduler with longer timeouts (24 hours vs 540 seconds with Cloud functions), Google App Engine task queues might be another service to consider.

You can deploy an app which will handle just the requests from a task queue. You can control the rate at which tasks are pushed or pulled from the queue. This gives you much more freedom both in terms of how much time you want to have a task running as well as retries and other logic. Since this is all done using App Engine, you will not need to worry about the infrastructure and resources but just about your handler code and versioning.

## [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview)

Cloud Pub/Sub is all more powerful queuing mechanism but you might have to manage the infrastructure from where you will be pulling items out of the topics you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks @Tuxdude. I considered this, but it doesn't handle retries (although you could just `nack` the message and try again). At least using Cloud Functions you don't have to have a separate process running somewhere to handle them.

Comment: @knation - You can do the retry within the cloud function handler. You have 540 seconds to process the response. If you need more time than that, you can consider App Engine task queues, which provide longer timeouts (24 hours) and still provides a serverless infrastructure for your handler.